# Referencing an array element in select Query in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, dynamic-sql

I am writing some Pl/SQl in which I used an array Variable of Length 5.

Then I stored all the Column name of another table into the above declared array.
Now I am looking  for a solution by which I can use the Array element in select Query to fetch the data from another table which exactly has the column name.
Like

```
arr(1):='Name'
arr(2):='Course'
```

The Query in Pl/Sql should be something like this (for reference only)

```
select arr(1) from Mttable;
```

==== This generates error when I write the Query in this way

Note- All work should be done in Pl/SQL on Oracle 10g

Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

You can build up a query in a string and execute the string.  My PL/SQL is rusty, but something like:

```
begin
   query := 'select ' || arr(1) || ' from Mttable';
   execute immediate query;
end;
```

Comment: This technique is called *dynamic SQL* and is needed whenever you need to use table or column names as variables in your SQL.